# Find part of specific text in row, copy to cell in same row, delete part of specific text from initial cell

Tags: excel, vba

You need to copy rows of text that contain part of the words "cat" or "Сat" from column "A" to column "B". Rows of column "A" in which "cat","Cat" are found, you need clear.

[image]
[image]

```
Option Compare Text
Public Sub Search_For()
Dim list

list = "Data_sheet"
row_number = 1
Do
row_number = row_number + 1
item_description = Sheets(list).Range("A" & row_number)
items_copied = Sheets(list).Range("B" & row_number)

If InStr(item_description, "Cat") Then
    Worksheets(list).Row(item_description).Copy
    items_copied.Paste
If InStr(item_description, "cat") Then
    Worksheets(list).Row(item_description).Copy
    items_copied.Paste
End If

Loop Until items_description = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Great code, what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify the problem you are running into with your code.

Answer (score 2):

To tidy up your code slightly, and get it working - see below:

```
Public Sub Search_For()
    Dim list As String, row_number As Long, item_description As String
    
    list = "Data_sheet"
    row_number = 1
    With Worksheets(list)
        Do
            row_number = row_number + 1
            item_description = .Cells(row_number, 1).Value
            
            If InStr(item_description, "Cat") Or InStr(item_description, "cat") Then
                .Cells(row_number, 2).Value = .Cells(row_number, 1).Value
                .Cells(row_number, 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Loop Until item_description = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Note:

If you want to ignore case *entirely*, then you could instead use:

```
If InStr(LCase(item_description), "cat") Then
```

Comment: `Option Compare Text` as in the original code should create complete case insensitivity without the need use `LCase` within the `Instr` functions.

Comment: Good point Ron, I missed that entirely from the original code.